# Filter out entries that appear more than once in a table

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I have a table that contains the following data:

```
Table t1

A     |   B
12        56
12        56
10        8
10        9
10        11
9         55
9         66
```

I need to write a program that finds all column values which have same value of column `A` but different values in column `B`.

**Example**

My result should be as follows:

```
A    |    B
10        8
10        9
10        11
9         55
9         66
```

`A` is the same and `B` is different for each value of `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct leftside.*
from t1 leftside 
inner join t1 rightside
where leftside.A = rightside.A
and leftside.B != rightside.B
order by A, B
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/578f2f/5

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT 
    A
    , B 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        A,
        B,
        COUNT(*) AS Total
    FROM 
        t1
    GROUP BY
        A,
        B
) AS Results
WHERE
    Results.Total = 1
```

This query will hide any entries that occur more than once in table `t1`.